# Find which nth occurrence of a day in a month for a date in Java

Tags: java, date

I need to find which nth dayOfWeek a particular day is in the month for a date in Java. For example, today is April 20th, 2016 which is the **3rd** Wednesday in the month or October 31, 2016 which is the **5th** Monday in October. How can I find which number the particular occurrence of a day is in the month?

Comment: Do you have _a_ approach before looking for the best?

Comment: Which version of Java? If less than 8, do you use Joda Time?

Comment: Java 7. Yes, we are using Joda time.

Comment: No, I have do not have a solution to the problem yet or I would not ask the question so please don't down vote me because I don't know the answer before I ask the question.

Comment: Please do some research before asking. There are a number of Related (possibly duplicate) posts on the right.

Comment: I have looked at several answers and none of them are the same as my question. There are many questions about the week number in a month but not finding which nth instance of a particular day a date is in a month.

Comment: The closest answer I have found is setting a date to the nth of some day of the week, such as the 4th Thursday of the month. I want to do the opposite. I want to know which nth occurrence a particular day is.

Comment: I honestly don't know why this is being down voted. It is a valid question. If there is a duplicate that I am not finding please point it out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the get method of the Calendar class.

```
public static int getOccurenceOfDayInMonth() {
    return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);
}
```

[EDIT]

Here is a solution given any date, rather than the current date.

```
public static int getOccurenceOfDayInMonth(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);

    return calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);
}
```

Comment: This actually works correctly. I generated 1000 days starting from 1-1-2016 and it returns the correct nth occurrence of a particular day of a month for any date.