# For a given date, detect the nth day-of-week in the month, then determine the same in next 6 months, in Java

Tags: java, java-time, dayofweek

For a given date, such as 2018-03-05, how do I detect that it is the first Monday of that month?

And after determining that fact, how do I calculate the same nth day-of-week in the month for the following six months? For example, Monday 2018-04-02 and Monday 2018-05-03.

Just like [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48604889/642706) but using Java.

I tried this code, but do not get the results I expect. What I expect:

> [2018-04-02, 2018-05-07, 2018-06-04, 2018-07-02, 2018-08-06, 2018-09-03]

Perhaps I misunderstand [`ChronoField.ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2018-03-05" );
int alignedDayOfWeekInMonth = ld.get( ChronoField.ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH );
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = ld.getDayOfWeek();
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( ld );

int countMonths = 6;
List < LocalDate > localDates = new ArrayList <>( countMonths );
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( alignedDayOfWeekInMonth , dayOfWeek );
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= countMonths ; i++ ) {
    LocalDate firstOfMonth = ym.plusMonths( i ).atDay( 1 );
    LocalDate localDate = firstOfMonth.with( ta );
    localDates.add( localDate );
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "ld.toString(): " + ld );
System.out.println( "alignedDayOfWeekInMonth: " + alignedDayOfWeekInMonth );
System.out.println( "dayOfWeek.toString(): " + dayOfWeek );
System.out.println("ym.toString(): " + ym);
System.out.println( "localDates: " + localDates );
```

When run.

```
ld.toString(): 2018-03-05
alignedDayOfWeekInMonth: 5
dayOfWeek.toString(): MONDAY
ym.toString(): 2018-03
localDates: [2018-04-30, 2018-06-04, 2018-07-02, 2018-07-30, 2018-09-03, 2018-10-01]
```

A related Question, but uses the legacy date-time classes rather than the modern *java.time* classes: [*Find which nth occurrence of a day in a month for a date in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36757031/642706)

Comment: Did i miss something or did you just us the wrong field? You use `ChronoField.ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH` but for `TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth` the suitable field would be `ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH`.

Comment: @devpuh I think my problem is the reverse. I want the behavior of `TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth` where 2018-03-05 is the first Monday of the month. Yet `ChronoField.ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH` gives me `5` as you can see in the output, rather than a `1`. What is that `5`? What exactly does `ChronoField.ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH` mean? The doc is not clear to me.

Comment: The field `ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH` belongs to `ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH` where the week doesn't start with a fixed `DAY_OF_WEEK` like Monday but with the first day of the month.

Answer (score 2):

This simple change fixes your program:

```
    int alignedWeekOfMonth = ld.get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH);
```

I have renamed your variable `alignedDayOfWeekInMonth`, though, so you need to carry the name change through to the two places where you are using it. Then your program prints:

```
ld.toString(): 2018-03-05
alignedWeekOfMonth: 1
dayOfWeek.toString(): MONDAY
ym.toString(): 2018-03
localDates: [2018-04-02, 2018-05-07, 2018-06-04, 2018-07-02, 2018-08-06, 2018-09-03]
```

The list agrees with what you said you expected.

It seems you were correct in that you had misunderstood `ChronoField.ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`. With reference to the concept of aligned weeks in month March 5 is the **5th** day in the **1st** aligned week. The chrono field you used gave you the 5, not the 1. To get the 1, use `ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH` instead. Then everything works.

Answer (score 1):

You used a wrong field for [`TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(int ordinal, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#dayOfWeekInMonth-int-java.time.DayOfWeek-) since `ordinal` is *the week within the month* but you used [`ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH)¹.

But how to you get the week of month in *java.time*?:
For this you need [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html), the most common is [`WeekFields.ISO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#ISO).
Now you can create a `ChronoField` for week of month with `WeekFields.ISO.weekOfMonth();`.

---

With your code this should look like:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2018-03-05" );
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = ld.getDayOfWeek();
int ordinal = ld.get(WeekFields.of(dayOfWeek, 7).weekOfMonth());
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( ld );

int countMonths = 6;
List < LocalDate > localDates = new ArrayList <>( countMonths );
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( ordinal, dayOfWeek );
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= countMonths ; i++ ) {
    LocalDate firstOfMonth = ym.plusMonths( i ).atDay( 1 );
    LocalDate localDate = firstOfMonth.with( ta );
    localDates.add( localDate );
}
```

---

¹: [`ChronoField.ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH) is the n-th day in a week which doesn't start with a fixed DAY_OF_WEEK like Monday but with the first day of the month.

Comment: The explanation is good, and the code works. Upvoted. The `WeekFields` class is not necessary, I think I consider it a bit overkill here.

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't fancy at all but it works :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2018-03-04" );
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY;

    LocalDate first = ld.withDayOfMonth(1);

    List<LocalDate> firstDays = new ArrayList<>();
    //I deliberately included the start date in the loop. 
    //Easily fixed if it shouldn't be included
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        LocalDate firstDay = getFirstDay(first.plusMonths(i), dayOfWeek);
        firstDays.add(firstDay);
    }
}

static LocalDate getFirstDay(LocalDate date, DayOfWeek searchedDay) {
    LocalDate temp = date;
    int i = 0;
    while (temp.getDayOfWeek() != searchedDay) {
         temp = date.plusDays(i++);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: No, that misses the essence of my Question: For any given date, how to determine if it is "first Monday" or "third Thursday"? Your Answer hard-codes "first Monday", but how to soft-code to project the following 6 months from *any* given date? See the middle of the Question’s title: *…detect the nth day-of-week in month…*

Comment: Ok, I missed that but it's easily fixed for my code. I'll update the answer.